# What is the idiomatic Hamcrest pattern to assert that each element of an iterable matches a given matcher?

Tags: java, idioms, hamcrest

Examine the following snippet:

```
    assertThat(
        Arrays.asList("1x", "2x", "3x", "4z"),
        not(hasItem(not(endsWith("x"))))
    );
```

This asserts that the list doesn't have an element that doesn't end with "x". This, of course, is the double negatives way of saying that all elements of the list ends with "x".

Also note that the snippet throws:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: not a collection containing not a string ending with "x"
     got: <[1x, 2x, 3x, 4z]>
```

This lists the entire list, instead of just the element that doesn't end with "x".

So is there an idiomatic way of:

- Asserting that each element ends with "x" (without double negatives)
- On assertion error, list only those elements that doesn't end with "x"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The matcher given by David Harkness produces a nice message for the **expected part**.
The message for the **actual part**, however, is also determined by which `assertThat` method you use:

The one from **JUnit** (`org.junit.Assert.assertThat`) produces the output you provided.

- With the `not(hasItem(not(...)))` matcher:

  ```
  java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expected: not a collection containing not a string ending with "x"
       got: <[1x, 2x, 3x, 4z]>
  ```
- With the `everyItem(...)` matcher:

  ```
  java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expected: every item is a string ending with "x"
       got: <[1x, 2x, 3x, 4z]>
  ```

The one from **Hamcrest** (`org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat`) produces the output given by David:

- With the `not(hasItem(not(...)))` matcher:

  ```
  java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expected: not a collection containing not a string ending with "x"
       but: was <[1x, 2x, 3x, 4z]>
  ```
- With the `everyItem(...)` matcher:

  ```
  java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expected: every item is a string ending with "x"
       but: an item was "4z"
  ```

My own experimentation with the Hamcrest assert showed me that the "but" part is often confusing, depending on how exactly multiple matchers are combined and which one fails first, and therefore I still stick to the JUnit assert, where I know quite exactly what I'll see in the "got" part.

Answer (score 23):

You are looking for `everyItem()`:

```
assertThat(
    Arrays.asList("1x", "2x", "3x", "4z"),
    everyItem(endsWith("x"))
);
```

This produces a nice failure message:

```
Expected: every item is a string ending with "x"
     but: an item was "4z"
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is quite old, but today, with Java 8, I'd rather write it with lambdas, e.g.

```
Stream.of("1x", "2x", "3x", "4z").allMatch(e->e.endsWith("x"));
```

[This is why.](http://java.dzone.com/articles/most-internal-dsls-are)

Comment: Good catch. But it seems to me that Harmcrest would still win because its failure messages would be more detailed about which item failed and why. But of course it would be nice to finally see such java8-ish assertThat API as mentioned in the article some time.