# Use Hamcrest's assertThat with several objects in one line?

Tags: junit, hamcrest

Can I use Hamcrest's `assertThat` to assert something about several objects in one line of code? The objects are not in a collection. For instance, I would like to `assertThat` four strings are equal. Also, how can I assert that all objects are null?

Comment: I found it difficult to read your original question. I've rewritten it, hope it still makes sense to you. If not, please edit it again (or let me know in a comment).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the idiomatic Hamcrest pattern to assert that each element of an iterable matches a given matcher?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985610/what-is-the-idiomatic-hamcrest-pattern-to-assert-that-each-element-of-an-iterabl)

Answer (score 1):

Use Hamcrest's [Every](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/Every.html)

```
assertThat(listOfStrings, Every.everyItem(CoreMatchers.equalTo("someValue"));
assertThat(listOfStrings, Every.everyItem(CoreMatchers.nullValue());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
assertThat("All values should be equals to origin", origin, allOf(is(str1), is(str2));
assertThat("All values should be null", null, allOf(is(obj1), is(obj2));
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the op and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: @reporter Note that this answerer *is* the OP (Q&A style). But your point is still valid.